# How to "catch" a form's post request status?

Tags: node.js, http

I am using Node.js(with express) to make a website and I'm pretty new at it. I am currently stuck on how to "catch"(not sure the proper term) a POST request response on the client side. I have a page that has a form that the user fills out. Once the user hit the submit button the server-side gets the information and process it. Then once done it sends a status code. What I want to do on the client side is "catch" that status code, depending on the code, if its good then redirect to the next page else pop up an alert to the user that something is wrong with their input(or something along those lines). If someone can show me the most simplest way of doing it, as I am still learning, I would appreciate it.

When I hit submit it changes my browser window blank with a text: 'OK'

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Index</title></head>
<body>
  <form action="/create" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="Message"></br>
    <input type="number" name="input2" value="0"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
//where I want to "catch" my post request response
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/views'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/create', function(req, res){
//abstract data and send to db
if(okay)
 res.sendStatus(200)
else
 res.sendStatus(400)
})
```

Comment: You need to send the POST as an Ajax request, rather than an HTML form submission.

Comment: @shaochuancs can you go more in depth in why I have to use an Ajax request? why can't I use a HTML form submission? it seems like I can access the variables just fine from the server side when I do it.

Comment: I've added my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

*When I hit submit it changes my browser window blank with a text: 'OK'...why can't I use a HTML form submission?*

That's because if it is a plain HTML form submission, the browser will send the HTTP request, get response from server, and display that response content as a new web page (and replace the old one).

*Why I have to use an Ajax request?*

To get resonse from server without refresh the page, you need to send an Ajax request. That is, send the HTTP request via JavaScript, rather than via HTML element. In this way, the response can be processed by JavaScript code (*"if its good then redirect to the next page else pop up an alert"*).

Example Ajax code is listed as below (using jQuery):

```
$.post('/create', {
  input1: 'Message',
  input2: 0
}).done(function(){
  // redirect to the next page.
}).fail(function(){
  // pop up an alert
});
```